# How to make a Object with propertis is a property of an object which is in another list

Tags: java, list, collections

Imagine that I have a list of certain objects:List, like

```
[Field name: id
 Field type: 8
 Field length: 3
 Field value: 156, Field name: name
 Field type: 253
 Field length: 15
 Field value: aaa]
```

And I need to generate another Target object

```
class Target {
    Integer id;
    String name;
}
```

including the id and name properties , which are name's value of Field Object, and their values are 156 and aaa, which are value's value of Field Object, so is is it possible to achieve this by using apache collections or guava? Which methods should be useful for my case?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You only need reflection.

Comment: can you show me some sample examples?really appreciated